# Why is not the QuoteMode = OptionalForBoth, quotechar = '"' the default option for all fields?

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I gave FileHelpers a spin and out-of-the-box it cannot handle lines such as `1,2,"Some Text, some other text", 02`. I have to add this attribute `[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.AllowForBoth)]` to each field in my record class that could be quoted. In my mind there should be an option that can be set to tell the reading engine to default all the fields to this mode. Is there such an option?  I could not find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is no global setting for handling quoted fields.

However, you can use [dynamic engine options](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/DynamicChangeOptions/) to set the properties in code.

```
var engine = new DelimitedFileEngine<MyFileHelpersClass>();
engine.Options.Fields[0].QuoteMode = TrimMode.OptionalForBoth;
engine.Options.Fields[0].MultilineMode = MultilineMode.AllowForBoth;
```